# jQueryMobile ListView Text Wrap

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

In jQueryMobile, listviews truncate text. There are lot of articles and posts [like this one](http://www.djchoi.com/code/text-wrapping-in-lists-in-jquery-mobile) that say to add white-space:normal in css.

However, this isn't working for me in jQueryMobile 1.4. You can see [here](http://vicinitybuzz.com/sb/#geo). To test you'll need to shrink your browser window size. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Given your LI markup:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1225696765/29072010042_normal.jpg" />
    <h3 class="wrap">Marco Alberto Sotelo (@marcosotelo79)</h3>
    <p>Sun Feb 02 20:01:24 +0000 2014</p>
    <p class="wrap">Ya estamis en el estadio MetLife para el @SuperBowl #SBUniversal http://t.co/80 /1wSo5O9E</p>
    <br />
    <img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bffo-1MCIAEoY5X.jpg" style="max-width: 90%; margin: auto;" />
  </a>
</li>
```

Change the class wrap to:

```
.wrap {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

The !important allows the class to override all the jQM classes that are setting it to nowrap.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/cqukt/)**

Comment: this is strange. Your demo works, but I can't get it to work on my page. I even put the style directly in the html header.

Comment: that was because I had moved to a different class. moved back and it works now. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<li><p class='ui-li-desc'>Text to be displayed</p></li>
```